# using svn propdel on multiple directories

Tags: svn

I need to use `svn propdel svn:externals` on multiple files/directories in the following directory structure:

```
Dir1/src/xxx/Adir
Dir1/src/xxx/Bdir
Dir1/src/xxx/Cdir
```

Every time I have to `cd` to each dir before I run the command `svn propdel svn:externals`.
Is there any way I can do it for all of them with just one command at `Dir1` level or `xxx` level?

Right now if I try the command at those levels I get an error

```
Attempting to delete nonexistent property 'svn:externals' on '.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a directory or directories as arguments to `svn propdel`:

```
svn propdel svn:externals dir1 dir2 dir3
```

You can also use the `--recursive` flag to delete the property from all directories in a tree:

```
svn propdel --recursive svn:externals parent_dir
```

If the property is not set for one of the directories you specify, you will get the `Attempting to delete nonexistent property` warning, but it's only a warning, you can ignore it.

Comment: This works! Thanks! I used -q flag to mute out the output.. so all the warning message no longer floods my screen.